# Android Location API not properly tracking the user

Tags: android, gps, location, location-provider, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have a background service which should track the user movement with his car, and send the data to my server. I have two variables for sending the location, either 60 seconds have passed or the user has moved 100 meters.

On my service here is how I start listening to locations:

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(100);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setInterval(60 * 1000);

mLocationClient = new LocationClient(context, connectionCallbacks, onConnectionFailedListener);
mLocationClient.connect();
```

and the listeners:

```
ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, locationListenerAPI);

        //process the last location, if available
        Location loc = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        if (loc != null) {
            prepareLocation(loc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
    }
};

LocationListener locationListenerAPI= new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //A location has been read, process it
        prepareLocation(location);
    }

};
```

So, while the service is running and I driver around with the car, onLocationChanged only fires a few times, it does not take into consideration either the time or meters to fire a location read. I have data connection and the GPS icon is visible on notification bar the whole time the service is running.

Any ideas why is not working ?

Comment: *I have two variables for sending the location, either 60 seconds have passed or the user has moved 100 meters* ...I belive it is not true ... after reading the docs i think that there is no **either** ... it is **and** ... so it provider checks only every 60 sec. and inform you if distance is more that 100m

Comment: So you mean, on first location sent it reads locationA and only after 60 seconds it reads locationB and if distance between LocationA and LocationB is bigger than 100m, it fires ?

Comment: That's how I understood the docs ... check what `getFastestInterval` returns ... AFAIK Interval means power up GPS(or other stuff depends - on Priority and permissions) and get location at Interval ... FastestInterval means if other app using GPS you can give me location update but not often then FastestInterval ... and SmallestDisplacement is somthing different ... by setting this to not 0 you are telling to provider: I do care only for changes *circa* SmallestDisplacement

Comment: @Selvin please add this as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: @Selvin SmallestDisplacement compares your last location to your current location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I just did it like this:

I've `setInterval(5000)` and `setFastestInterval(5000)` and then, for each read location, if distance between them is bigger than 100m, I send the location to my server. I gave up on using `smallestDisplacement`. This seem to work reliably.